# Acceder a elementos de layout cargados con view Pager

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo una actividad con tres layout.

```
 activity_welcome.xml
 activity_detalle_refaccion.xml
 visor_de_imagenes.xml
```

Que cargo con este código en un `ViewPager`:

```
public class DetalleRefaccion extends UtilidadesActividades {

    private Bitmap loadedImage;


    private int[] layouts;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        layouts = new int[]{

                R.layout.activity_detalle_refaccion,
                R.layout.visor_de_imagenes
        };

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

    }

  class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
```

Esto funciona correctamente. Se muestran los dos layouts dentro del panel `activity_welcome.xml`. Pero intento acceder a los `@id/` del layout `activity_detalle_refaccion` con un

`TextView codigoInterno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codigoInterno);`

pero obtengo null y mi aplicación se cierra.

Si yo modifico `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);` por el layout `activity_detalle_refaccion.xml` obtengo fácilmente sus id. ***Entonces ¿Cómo acceder a este `TextView` en el layout que no está en `setContentView`?***

Comment: A ver si entendi, desde `DetalleRefaccion` quieres acceder a uno de los elementos que esta en el `ViewPager`?

Comment: @Einer Es correcto. Pero la aplicación se cierra cuando lo intento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes acceder a los elementos de una vista que esta en el `ViewPager`. Hasta la fecha la clase `ViewPager` no expone ninguna sobrecarga donde esto sea posible y no creo que la exponga por motivo de colision de elementos que tengan el mismo id.

Si de verdad necesitas eso, una solucion que me funciono fue exponer la vista del elemento al que necesito acceder. Por ejemplo en tu caso solo tendrias que hacer esto:

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public View refaccionView;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
        container.addView(view);


        // si es el layout refaccion, entonces le indicamos la referencia al campo
        if(layouts[position] == R.layout.activity_detalle_refaccion)
        {
            refaccionView = view;
        }


        return view;
    }

    //...
```

Entonces cuando lo vayas a utilizar, solo tendrias que acceder la a propiedad `refraccionView` y buscar tu elemento:

```
  //...

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        layouts = new int[]{

                R.layout.activity_detalle_refaccion,
                R.layout.visor_de_imagenes
        };

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);

        TextView codigoInterno = (TextView)myViewPagerAdapter.refaccionView.findViewById(R.id.codigoInterno);


    }

    //...
```

Recuerda que debes primero inicializar el `ViewPager` para luego acceder a la vista de refraccion.

Comment: Funciono. Solo que tuve que esperar a que `viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);` terminara de cargar con un `AsyncTask`. Gracias.